# Resume music button for action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 2 buttons: 1 resume(onBtn) and 1 pause(offBtn) which are allotted for controlling the sounds of animation.. pause button works fine but when I play it again... it restart the song from the beginning and not on it's suppose resumeTime... here is my code...

---

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

onBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startMove);
offBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMove);

var resumeTime:Number = 0;
var isPlaying:Boolean;
var mySound:Sound = new MySong();
var channel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();


onBtn.visible=false;
isPlaying=true;
channel1=mySound.play();


function stopMove(event:MouseEvent):void {

    resumeTime=channel1.position;
    channel1.stop();
    onBtn.visible =true;
    offBtn.visible=false;
    isPlaying=false;
    stop();

}

function startMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    channel1=mySound.play(resumeTime);
    onBtn.visible=false;
    offBtn.visible=true;
    isPlaying=true;
    play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your animation in a separate `MovieClip` then on `stopMove()` and `startMove()` you call the `play()` and `stop()` functions of that `MovieClip`.

Here's a working example: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1360494138

And the changes in your code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop(); ////

onBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startMove);
offBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMove);

var resumeTime:Number = 0;
var isPlaying:Boolean;
var mySound:Sound = new MySong();
var channel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

onBtn.visible=false;
isPlaying=true;
channel1=mySound.play(0);


function stopMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    resumeTime=channel1.position;
    channel1.stop();
    onBtn.visible =true;
    offBtn.visible=false;
    isPlaying=false;
    movieClip.stop(); //// Animation moved to movieClip
}

function startMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(resumeTime >= mySound.length) {
    //// Go back to start when sound has finished playing
    resumeTime = 0;
    }
    channel1=mySound.play(resumeTime);
    onBtn.visible=false;
    offBtn.visible=true;
    isPlaying=true;
    movieClip.play(); //// Animation moved to movieClip
}
```

Comment: Came up with a workaround to that problem and edited my first post.